# get double value from bigdecimal without exponential java

Tags: double, bigdecimal, exponential

is there a way to get double from BigDecimal without exponential?

Eg: I have an `new BigDecimal("123456797676.897")`

if i print `new BigDecimal("123456797676.897").toString()` it prints properly as `123456797676.897`.

Now suppose if I try to print `new BigDecimal("123456797676.897").doubleValue()`, it prints with exponential like `1.23456797676897E11`.

Is there any way I can get doublevalue with out exponential.

Thanks :)

Comment: The exponential is just a matter of formatting. If you don't like how a double is printed, look at DecimalFormat.

Comment: DecimalFormat will return in string format, again if I convert it to Double it comes as exponential only. if u know some way just explain with example. it would be helpful.

Comment: The exponent is **only** a matter of how it is displayed, something that can and should be controlled using DecimalFormat in any context for which the default is not suitable. The internal representation of a double has nothing at all to do with radix 10 exponents.

Answer (score 2):

The following program demonstrates that these are all exactly the same double:

```
new BigDecimal("123456797676.897").doubleValue()
123456797676.897
1.23456797676897E11
12.3456797676897E10
```

The [Double toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) method has to pick one representation for each value. For numbers greater than 10<sup>7</sup> it uses exponential notation with a single digit before the decimal point. That is a generally reasonable choice, but it is not always the right choice. If you want it displayed without the exponent use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). If you are just using the number, it makes no difference whether Double's toString would have displayed it with an exponent or not, and you don't need to do anything about it.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double doubleValue = new BigDecimal("123456797676.897").doubleValue();
    double simpleLiteral = 123456797676.897;
    double exponent11Literal = 1.23456797676897E11;
    double exponent10Literal = 12.3456797676897E10;

    System.out.println(doubleValue == simpleLiteral);
    System.out.println(doubleValue == exponent11Literal);
    System.out.println(doubleValue == exponent10Literal);
  }
}
```

output:

```
true
true
true
```